# Jquery .click show/hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a form hidden and a message show up when the send button is clicked. I have tried a number of things It was in a document.ready function but that seemed to cause more errors than it fixed. This is how the code stands currently;

```
                    <form class="contact">
                    <p class="contact-name">
                        <label class="contact-author">Name*</label>
                        <input class="input-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-email">
                        <label class="contact-author">Email*</label>
                        <input class="input-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-msg">
                        <label class="contact-author">Message*</label>
                        <textarea class="input-msg" type="text" name="comments" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea><br>
                    </p>
                    <p class="contact-send">
                        <input class="input-send" id="send" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
                    </p>
                </form>
                        <div id="send-msg" style="visibility:hidden;">
                            <p>Thanks your message has been sent!</p>
                        </div>


$('#send').click(function() {
$('.contact').hide();
$('#send-msg').show();
)};
```

JSFiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/rvfhu/

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle
2. Your closing `)}` should actually be `})`
3. When using CSS to hide elements, use `display: none;`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvfhu/6/

Comment: Aha Thanks Apologies will vote as answer when I can thanks again!